# My question is about is to know the data structure of firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures

I want to know structure of firebase database of code.

I have completed my code but I didn't know the structure of database.

**WallpapersActivity.java**

```
public class WallpapersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Wallpaper> wallpaperList;
    List<Wallpaper> favList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    WallpapersAdapter adapter;
    DatabaseReference dbWallpapers, dbFavs;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpapers);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(category);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        favList = new ArrayList<>();
        wallpaperList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new WallpapersAdapter(this, wallpaperList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        dbWallpapers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images")
                .child(category);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            dbFavs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child("favourites")
                    .child(category);
            fetchFavWallpapers(category);
        } else {
            fetchWallpapers(category);
        }
    }
    private void fetchFavWallpapers(final String category) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbFavs.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot wallpaperSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String id = wallpaperSnapshot.getKey();
                        String title = wallpaperSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                        String desc = wallpaperSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = wallpaperSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
                        Wallpaper w = new Wallpaper(id, title, desc, url, category);
                        favList.add(w);
                    }
                }
                fetchWallpapers(category);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    private void fetchWallpapers(final String category) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbWallpapers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot wallpaperSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String id = wallpaperSnapshot.getKey();
                        String title = wallpaperSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                        String desc = wallpaperSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = wallpaperSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
                        Wallpaper w = new Wallpaper(id, title, desc, url, category);
                        if (isFavourite(w)) {
                            w.isFavourite = true;
                        }
                        wallpaperList.add(w);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
    private boolean isFavourite(Wallpaper w) {
        for (Wallpaper f : favList) {
            if (f.id.equals(w.id)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Wallpaper.java**

```
public class Wallpaper {

    @Exclude
    public String id;
    public String title, desc, url;
    @Exclude
    public String category;
    @Exclude
    public boolean isFavourite = false;
    public Wallpaper(String id, String title, String desc, String url, String category) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.url = url;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

**Category.java**

```
public class Category {

    public String name, desc, thumb;
    public Category(String name, String desc, String thumb) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private DatabaseReference dbCategories;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CategoriesAdapter adapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        dbCategories = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("categories");
        dbCategories.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = ds.getKey();
                        String desc = ds.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String thumb = ds.child("thumbnail").getValue(String.class);
                        Category c = new Category(name, desc, thumb);
                        categoryList.add(c);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to learn the JSON structure that corresponds to your code, is to write an instance of each Java class to the database.

But from a quick scan I'd expect:

```
"Wallpaper": {
    "title": "value of title", 
    "desc": "value of desc", 
    "url": "value of url"
}
```

Comment: But here I am using Firebase as a database so can you giveme the structure of that?

Comment: This **is** the structure of the JSON in a Firebase Realtime Database.